# About Fees in the Plutus Playground

Tags: plutus-pioneer-program, plutus-playground

I had been reviewing sample codes that can be run in the Plutus Playground, particularly the Vesting.hs code in Cohort #3 Week #3 of PPP.  So while trying several cases in the simulation, I sometimes encounter errors related to fees, so therefore it generated my curiosity on the following questions about fees:

1. The 10 lovelaces fees charged during the "Give" operation (Vesting.hs), is this a standard fee when sending ada via smart contracts?  Or this setting is intended only for Plutus Playground?  If so, where is this setting defined for Plutus Playground?
2. I also noticed that the playground throws an error for any value less than 2,000,000 lovelaces that I try to send for simulation of Vesting.hs. So similar to question #1, is this setting a standard for Cardano smart contracts?  Was it set differently from the Mainnet Network?  (I understand that the minimum Ada value in Mainnet is 1,000,000 lovelaces)  If so, where is this setting for Plutus Playground defined?
3. In the "Grab" operation (Vesting.hs), I noticed that the fee charged to the beneficiary is considerably higher. (When I tried, it is roughly 4,500 lovelaces).  Again, what is the basis of this fee setting?  Where is it defined?
4. I executed "Give" several times and it made several UTxOs for the beneficiary.  After I performed the "Grab", it charged the beneficiary lovelaces apparently for each UTxO that was created, so it means it charged the beneficiary considerably higher fees.  Is this expected for a Smart Contract operation?  Will this be same expectations when executed in Mainnet?

Comment: The default Playground fees are very unrealistic. In reality it starts around 160000 lovelace for a simple tx https://testnets.cardano.org/en/testnets/cardano/tools/plutus-fee-estimator/